# Why do I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object when running Update-Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core

First time working with entity framework, I've been testing with an in memory database which has been working fine but wanted to start working on a persistent database using sqlite.

I've got the model and context created, when I run Add-Migration in the Package Manager Console it seems to work fine but when I then run the Update-Database function I always get a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error but I can't work out why, any help really appreciated, been searching around for a while and can't see anything.

[Screenshot of the reported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xnQm.png)

I've got four model classes and the context class so not sure I can include all the code snippets here but happy to if folk think it's needed to get anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you passing in the migration name to [Update-Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#update-database)?

Comment: No, I am passing in the Context name, is it supposed to be the migration name created by the Add-Migration call?

Answer (score 1):

OK so I found out what the issue was.  The "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in this case was due to the fact that I didn't have a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.  I did have a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core which is what allowed the project to build OK but apparently this is required for the Update-Database call.

Also for anyone else needing to take a step back and just confirm they aren't going crazy, this is a good [website](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-api-ef-core-code-first/) describing what is needed.  I used this just to confirm everything worked OK and I hadn't missed something (which I obviously had).

**TL:DR** - Make sure you have a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite