# C# WPF Entity Framework Update Database causes Object reference error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a WPF application that is supposed to connect to an sqlite db.

Here is my ContextFactory:

```
 public class DataContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataDbContext>
{
    public DataContextFactory()
    {
        
    }

    public DataDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        //For migrations
        //Use Environment Variables instead of appsettings
        //Debugger.Launch();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataDbContext>();
        var cs = @"Filename=medicalrecalculation.sqlite;";
        builder.UseSqlite(cs);
        return new DataDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

This is my DbContext:

```
public class DataDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public DataDbContext(DbContextOptions<DataDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<LOB001MedicalAdditionalProcessingData> LOB001MedicalAdditionalProcessingData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=medicalrecalculation.sqlite");
    }
    //Seed must contain static data to prevent migrations from updating
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

}
```

I am able to create migrations using the cli like this:

> Add-Migration BaseMigration -Context DataDbContext -OutputDir
> Migrations

However, when I run Update-Database -Context DataDbContext, I get this error:

> Build started... Build succeeded. System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean
> errorsExpected)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
> errorsExpected)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tried adjusting the connection string and even creating an empty .sqlite file but it still shows this error.

Comment: No? I'm asking why I'm getting an object reference error when I run a command? Nothing in my code is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. [Why do I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object when running Update-Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081162/why-do-i-get-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-running-u)

Turns out I needed both EntityFramework.Core.Sqlite and EntityFramework.Sqlite.Core

Comment: No, you only need a reference to [`Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/7.0.0-preview.1.22076.6), because it includes the reference to `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Sqlite.Core` which [README](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core/) tells you *This package does not include a copy of the native SQLite library.* and that is the main problem